# How to make Flask scroll to a part of the page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

My website has one page with several sections. It has links that look like the following that scroll the user to the indicated section.

```
<a href="#section">Section</a>
```

Typing www.my-site.com#section will also do the trick.

How do I make Flask scroll to a section of the page when calling render_template('page.html')? Is there a way to do something like

```
render_template('page.html', section=section)
```

and then in the html do

```
{% if section %}
scroll_to_section
{% endif %}
```

? I seriously have no idea how to handle this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have jquery loaded in the page already:

Add this:

```
{% if section %}
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#{{ section }}").offset().top }, 500);
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

This will execute a scroll after the page has loaded. It will scroll to the top of the element with id `section` with a 500ms delay.

Comment: What should I put in place of ("html, body")? Or is that always the same? Also if I don't want a delay do I just remove the 500 or do I need to change the whole line?

Comment: Keep html, body. If you dont care about aninating just replace with $("html, body").scrollTop($("#{{ section }}").offset().top);

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JQuery in the following way:

```
{% if section %}
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("html, body").scrollTop( $("#{{ section }}").offset().top );
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Or in pure Javascript using [`location.hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp):

```
{% if section %}
<script>
    $(function() { 
       location.hash = "#{{ section }}" 
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

If you need to animate, [@Jean-Marc S. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29328877/4749719) is the way to go.